# Ember relationship: TypeError: Cannot set property 'store' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm getting the following error on my first Ember.js App with a Node.JS backend:

```
Intermediate-transitioned into 'loading' ember-1.5.0.js:3521
Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot set property 'store' of undefined
at DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.modelFor (http://127.0.0.1:5555/js/libs/ember-data.js:2986:31)
at DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.recordForId (http://127.0.0.1:5555/js/libs/ember-data.js:2437:29)
at deserializeRecordId (http://127.0.0.1:5555/js/libs/ember-data.js:3355:35)
at http://127.0.0.1:5555/js/libs/ember-data.js:3333:21
at http://127.0.0.1:5555/js/libs/ember-data.js:7117:30
at http://127.0.0.1:5555/js/libs/ember-1.5.0.js:3428:30
at Object.OrderedSet.forEach (http://127.0.0.1:5555/js/libs/ember-1.5.0.js:3271:24)
at Object.Map.forEach (http://127.0.0.1:5555/js/libs/ember-1.5.0.js:3426:22)
at Function.DS.Model.reopenClass.eachRelationship (http://127.0.0.1:5555/js/libs/ember-data.js:7116:50)
at normalizeRelationships (http://127.0.0.1:5555/js/libs/ember-data.js:3319:18) ember-1.5.0.js:3521
Transition #0: games: transition was aborted
```

The following json gets returned by /games

```
{
  "games": [
    {
      "serverSeedHash": "5eb59053dcb5810322e367245f631a65589ddf7bbe950d2986a43a5f376312ef",
      "id": 2,
      "serverSeed": null,
      "table": [
        1
      ],
      "amountOfPlayers": 2,
      "prizePool": 39600
    }
  ],
  "tables": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "minimumPlayers": 2,
      "maximumPlayers": 100,
      "cardPrice": 1000,
      "games": [
        2
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My complete Ember.js app.js looks like this:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true
});

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route('games', { path: '/' });
});

App.Game = DS.Model.extend({
    serverSeedHash: DS.attr(),
    serverSeed: DS.attr(),
    amountOfPlayers: DS.attr(),
    prizePool: DS.attr(),
    table: DS.belongsTo('table')
});

App.Table = DS.Model.extend({
    minimumPlayers: DS.attr(),
    maximumPlayers: DS.attr(),
    games: DS.hasMany('game')
});


App.GamesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('game');
    }
});
```

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting an error? Please note this is my first time toying with Ember.JS.
I've been breaking my had over this for the past days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `game` model, you're defining `table` as a `belongsTo` relationship, so Ember is expecting it to be singular where you're sending it an array. Change your object to this, and it should work:

```
{
  "games": [
    {
      ...
      "table": 1,
      ...
    }
  ],
  "tables": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix the problem.

I forgot to tell, the code did work before I start defining the relationships. So after adding App.Table model it broke.

Comment: Okay. Looking closer, you're defining `table` in the Game model as a singular `belongsTo` relationship, but you're sending it an array of tables. If you just send it `... table: 1, ...`, does that fix it?

Comment: That fixed it...
Seriously, I should have asked someone else earlier, so much frustration over something so little.

Comment: Yeah, that's programming... I revised the answer accordingly.